# how to set options in Select dropdown from an array returned from webservice in react js

Tags: reactjs, select, dropdown

Im new to react trying to populate the dropdown with the data i receive from webservice...

the webservice data i get is in the following format

```
       {
           "status":1,
           "yearList":[{"year":"2021","fromDate":null,"toDate":null},
                      {"year":"2021","fromDate":null,"toDate":null},
                      {"year":"2021","fromDate":null,"toDate":null},
                      {"year":"2021","fromDate":null,"toDate":null},
                      {"year":"2021","fromDate":null,"toDate":null}]

        }
     I need my select dropdown to be populated only with the year field.....

   This is the code....where im setting the state with data from webservice
        this.taxService.getFinancialYearsList().then(data=>{
        console.log(" year data is "+JSON.stringify(data))
        if(data.status == 1)
         {          
           this.setState({yeardata:data?.yearList})
          
    }
})

       and in render
        <select className="select2 form-control required finyear"  
         disabled={false}
         value={this.state.yearSelected}
         onChange={(e)=> 
            this.setState({yearSelected:e.currentTarget.value})}
            >
                                                    
          {this.state.yeardata?.map((item,i)=>{
           <option key={i} value={item.year}>
            {item.year}
            </option>
             })}
            </select>
```

Nothing is getting populated...the console.log is printing the data correctly like i mentioned in the starting of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this code

```html
                  <select
                          disabled={false}
                          value={select}
                          onChange={(e) => setSelected(e.currentTarget.value)}
                      >
                          {webserviceData.yearList.map((item,index) => (
                          <option key={index} value={item.year}>
                              {item.year}
                          </option>
                          ))}
                      </select>
```

Comment: thnks its done..

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could add some more code to your question, but assuming that you have:

```
  const r = {
    status: 1,
    yearList: [
      { year: "2021", fromDate: null, toDate: null },
      { year: "2021", fromDate: null, toDate: null },
      { year: "2021", fromDate: null, toDate: null },
      { year: "2021", fromDate: null, toDate: null },
      { year: "2021", fromDate: null, toDate: null }
    ]
  };
```

You could use:

```
    <select name="year">
      {r.yearList.map((item) => (
        <option value={item.year}>{item.year}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
```

To extract unique years you can use map and filter method like so:

```
  const uniqueYears = r.yearList
    .map((item) => item.year)
    .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);
```